# #NAME? on UDF that previously worked

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I created a VBA function:

```
Function LOJA(x As String)
Dim a As Integer
Dim f As String
Dim f2 As String
Dim f3 As String
a = InStr(1, x, "-")
f = Right(x, Len(x) - a)
a = InStr(1, f, "-")
f2 = Right(f, Len(f) - a)
a = InStr(1, f2, "-")
f3 = Left(f2, a - 2)
LOJA = f3
End Function
```

And it was working exactly like it was suppose to, I even ran the function on all the 300k lines I needed.

But before lunch, I saved Excel and closed it, and when I came back, the function keep giving me this error, smaller functions like it also give the same error like:

```
Function Center(x As String)
Dim a As Integer
Dim f As String
a = InStr(1, x, "-")
f = Right(x, Len(x) - a)
Center = f
End Function
```

Any idea what happened? What can be done to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do the UDFs appear when you begin to type them? Are they in the open workbook? Did you save them in `.xlsm` format?

[#NAME](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-a-NAME-error-7b73ddd3-2f9f-4701-9a34-199550e0cd70) errors usually indicate the formula typed isn't a defined formula.